# Group By and Average Flat Data in DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

**Input:**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,2 qty
282,apple,red,today,3 qty, 
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,,
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,1 qty,
```

**Output:**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,2 qty
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,1 qty,
```

**Attempted:**
but having this error: Cannot coerce Object to String

```
(payload groupBy (key,index) ->(key.number ++ key.join_date)) mapObject {
   a: {
       number: $[0].number,
       fruit: $[0].fruit,
       colour: $[0].colour,
       join_date:$[0].join_date,
       avginqty: sum($.avginqty)/sizeOf($.avginqty),
       avgoutqty: sum($.avgoutqty)/sizeOf($.avgoutqty)
   }
}
```

Comment: Your input has a space after 3 instead of "" . Is that how its supposed to be ? As well your output doesnt seem to be consistent with the input. Are you trying to get an average from the two rows into one row for qty?

Comment: Hi Salim, I am trying to get the average quantity based on the join_date and number. Sometimes , the rows will have empty value

Comment: An empty should be represented consistently with either "" or " " and not a mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following **input**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty
282,apple,red,today,3,2
282,apple,red,today,3,
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,,
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,1,
```

and using the following **script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
import * from dw::core::Arrays
---

(payload groupBy (key,index) ->(key.number ++ key.join_date)) mapObject {
   a: {
       number: $[0].number,
       fruit: $[0].fruit,
       colour: $[0].colour,
       join_date:$[0].join_date,
       avginqty: ($.avginqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/sizeOf($.avginqty) ++ " qty",
       avgoutqty: ($.avgoutqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/sizeOf($.avgoutqty) ++ " qty"    
   }
} pluck $
```

you would get the output as

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,1 qty
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,0.5 qty,0 qty
```

In one of your previous questions (Which i had answered with 4 variations (one of those scenarios does address your last ask (if the input has qty String as a part of the quantity).. However you could use the following

**Input**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,2 qty
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,3 qty
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,2 qty,2 qty
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,1 qty,1 qty
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
import * from dw::core::Arrays
---

(payload groupBy (key,index) ->(key.number ++ key.join_date)) mapObject {
   a: {
       number: $[0].number,
       fruit: $[0].fruit,
       colour: $[0].colour,
       join_date:$[0].join_date,
       avginqty: ($.avginqty sumBy (if(($ splitBy " ")[0] == "") 0 else ($ splitBy " ")[0] as Number ))/sizeOf($.avginqty) ++ " qty",
       avgoutqty: ($.avgoutqty sumBy (if(($ splitBy " ")[0] == "") 0 else ($ splitBy " ")[0] as Number))/sizeOf($.avgoutqty) ++ " qty"    
   }
} pluck $
```

**Output**

```
number,fruit,colour,join_date,avginqty,avgoutqty
282,apple,red,today,3 qty,2.5 qty
282,banana,yellow,yesterday,1.5 qty,1.5 qty
```

In case you would want to skip the rows which have qty as "" for avg calculation. Though this can lead to Division By Zero error in an edge case where all rows have one of those quantities as ""

```
avginqty: ($.avginqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty",
avgoutqty: ($.avgoutqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty"
```

To avoid DBZ error

```
avginqty: if((sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) != 0) ($.avginqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avginqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else "", 
avgoutqty: if((sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) != 0) ($.avgoutqty sumBy (if($ == "") 0 else $))/(sizeOf($.avgoutqty filter $ != "")) ++ " qty" else ""
```

Screenshot with a different input configured. (all values)

[image]

Comment: If the input has 'qty' for avginqty column?

Comment: then it would take the quantity.. per the if else condition

Comment: what i mean in the beginning if the input is eg. 1 qty, instead of 1

Comment: i had already addressed that in one of your previous questions. However i have updated the above answer with that approach as well. You would split the entry (1 qty on " ") and pick the first element and use it as Number to do the math in the script.

Comment: okay, how to exclude the row if the inout for avginqty and angoutqty is empty? to exclude these rows for calculation

Comment: you don't have to exclude.. if you see the logic it replaces the occurrence of  empty with 0 .

Comment: because i have tested and when it is 0, it will count the row to divide, for example, when the row is  0, the number to divide is +1

Comment: You can do a filter on the array when doing the count to remove all elements where $ == " " though you got to be careful about the fact that if all you have is " " for a given avgInqty or avgOutQty you could run into Division by Zero error. I pasted a quick code snippet at the end of the answer.

Comment: is there way to avoid division by zero error? for example if the entire column is empty then dont do the calculation?

Comment: You could do if else on the size prior to calculating the average. see the edited answer above.

Comment: hi, can i check with you how to get the most frequent number? for example, there are 2 of '1 qty' and '1' of  '3 qty', so will result in output of '2 qty'?

Comment: You need to ask that as a separate question. Be clear in your ask with the input , script that you have worked out this far and the expected output. Don't keep on changing the content of the ask in the same question.